# application link between server and laptop

Tags: laptop, windows-server-2008

wonder if there is a way to launch a program like "BitTorrent" on my laptop ,

which is actually running on my windows server 2008 r2 ?

so basically when i click the BitTorrent icon on my laptop to be like a short-cut that points to the BitTorrent installed on my server and everything that BitTorrent does to be saved on that server ( downloads ...uploads ... etc..)

thanks

Comment: Do you want the program its-self to run on the Server? I'm not 100% sure what you're aiming at here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can so that using the [**RemoteApp**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753844(WS.10).aspx) feature of RDP services (Terminal Services was the old name).

I have found that it is even possible using RemoteApp on desktop versions of Windows, with a little .rdp file and registry editing.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative could you just use Remote Desktop to connect to the server and run the application there. It's not exactly what you want but provides 99% of what you need.

Comment: RemoteApp is part of RDP services, and does exactly what he wants.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that, very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest some hacky ways in which I would do this:

1) If you are running a web-server on your "server", create a PHP script that will launch bittorent (with your parameters). Make sure to include some authentication logic and use HTTPS preferably.

2) You could use AUTO-IT (windows) or xdotool (linux) to automate such tasks. For example, in few lines, you can write a script to launch putty, ssh to your server, and type commands to run on the server. www.autoitscript.com. www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/

Using both 1) and 2), you can create a single click launcher for what you want.

There may be custom solutions a single task like this, but AutoIT/xdotool kind of things are very generic and useful.